# Error while deploy nextjs in firebase hosting - Invalid value specified for cpu

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I am getting error while deploying nextjs 13 in firebase hosting through firebase-tools.

error - `HTTP Error: 400, Could not create Cloud Run service ssrlyeanabot. spec.template.spec.containers.resources.limits.cpu: Invalid value specified for cpu. For the specified value, maxScale may not exceed 30.\nConsider running your workload in a region with greater capacity, decreasing your requested cpu-per-instance, or requesting an increase in quota for this region if you are seeing sustained usage near this limit, see https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas. Your project may gain access to further scaling by adding billing information to your account."`

```
 Error: Failed to create function ssrlyeanabot in region us-central1
```

package.json -

```
{
  "name": "testing",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.36.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.2.4",
    "next": "13.2.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  }
}
```

firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "source": ".",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "us-central1"
    }
  }
}
```

firebase tools version -  `11.25.1`

**STEP TO REPRODUCE THIS PROBLEM**

1. npx create-next-app@latest
2. firebase experiments:enable webframeworks
3. firebase init hosting
4. firebase deploy
   [done]
   IMP -> enable billing.

Please let me know, What should I do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add key `maxInstances: <some number less 30>` to `frameworksBackend` section of firebase.json file

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "source": ".",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "us-central1",
      "maxInstances": 2
    }
  }
}
```

Explanation:

deployment is failing when Firebase CLI is trying to create a cloud function to support Nextjs Framework.

using `firebase --debug deploy` it seems CLI is not passing `maxInstance` parameter to create cloud function which results in error.

set `maxInstances` to specify maximum number of instance you need for this function ( should be less than your project quota - 30 )

schema for [firebase.json](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/blob/master/schema/firebase-config.json#L61-L64)

Comment: Now, I get it.  Earlier it used to be pre-set.

Comment: I tried setting it to 20 with no luck, but at 10, which is what they recommend, it worked.